# Order buttons that represent attached monitors by Windows Display order

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the below code to draw a button(s) onto a panel for each monitor that is currently connected to the PC.

```
var padding = 5;
var buttonSize = new Size(95, 75);
for (int i = 0; i < Screen.AllScreens.Length; i++)
{
    var screen = Screen.AllScreens[i];
    Button monitor = new Button
    {
        Name = "Monitor" + screen,
        AutoSize = true,
        Size = buttonSize,
        Location = new Point(12 + i * (buttonSize.Width + padding), 14),
        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
        BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.display_enabled,
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold),
        ForeColor = Color.White,
        BackColor = Color.Transparent,
        Text = screen.Bounds.Width + "x" + screen.Bounds.Height
    };

    monitorPanel.Controls.Add(monitor);
}
```

For devices with one or more monitors attached, the code works just fine and this is the end result:

[image]

However, while it works, I'd like to (if possible) order them as they appear in the Windows display view:

[image]

In the first screenshot, they are ordered as 2 | 3 | 1 instead of 3 | 2 | 1.

Is what I'm after possible?

Comment: Recently, in a similar situation, I ordered the returned `Screen`s in the collection by the start X positions of the bounds of each monitor (in my case, each monitor started from a higher X coordinate; I don't know whether this is universally true).

Comment: You can use `dmPosition` . [refer this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple screens in Windows are handled as one, big, "glued" working area. Based on that, order of screens in configuration is according to their position in the new working area. Assuming that all of your screens are in one line, you can just use

`screen.Bounds.X`

as ordering property. If the screens are layed out in multiple rows, then ordering will also have to consider `Y` component.

EDIT: 
You could just use Linq for sorting, specifically [OrderBy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx).
Example usage for case when screens are in one row and collection will be iterated once.

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < Screen.AllScreens.Length; i++)
{
   var screen = Screen.AllScreens[i];
```

to

```
foreach(var screen in Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(i => i.Bounds.X))
{
```

Comment: In what differs your answer from my comment above?

Comment: @UweKeim, firstly, I explained why this works. Secondly: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't suppose you could elaborate a bit more on 'how' to use the ordering property in my example? I'm still fairly new to coding and I've not had much luck attempting to order the monitors.

Comment: Thanks. After a bit of fiddling, it appears to be working. :)

Comment: Sorry @Rawns, I missed a fact that you use your `i` later. One of the correct ways to modify your code would be to create a new variable before the loop with value of `Screen.AllScreens.OrderBy(i => i.Bounds.X).ToList()` and use this variable instead of `Screen.AllScreens`. Happy to know you fixed that.